# How to use mapM_ in this situation

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism, map-function, foldable

I am trying to print different components of result of [autocorrelation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/statistics-0.15.0.0/docs/Statistics-Autocorrelation.html) on different lines:

```
import Data.Vector as V
import Statistics.Autocorrelation
import Data.Typeable

sampleA = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4]

main = do
    let res = autocorrelation $ V.fromList sampleA
    putStr "Type of result of autocorrelation test: "
    print $ typeOf res
    print res
    -- Prelude.mapM_ print res      -- not working;
```

The output is:

```
Type of result of autocorrelation test: ((Vector Double),(Vector Double),(Vector Double))

([1.0,2.5e-2,-0.45,-0.325,0.5,0.125,-0.15],[1.0,-1.3255000000000001,-1.4039375473415425,-1.442999810318651,-1.5311377955236107,-1.5364636906417393,-1.544097864842309],[1.0,1.0755000000000001,1.1539375473415425,1.192999810318651,1.2811377955236107,1.2864636906417393,1.294097864842309])
```

However, if I uncomment last line, I get error:

```
• No instance for (Foldable ((,,) (Vector Double) (Vector Double)))
    arising from a use of ‘Prelude.mapM_’
• In a stmt of a 'do' block: Prelude.mapM_ print res
  In the expression:
    do { let res = autocorrelation $ fromList sampleA;
         putStr "Type of result of autocorrelation test: ";
         print $ typeOf res;
         print res;
         .... }
  In an equation for ‘main’:
      main
        = do { let res = ...;
               putStr "Type of result of autocorrelation test: ";
               print $ typeOf res;
               .... }
```

How can I print all parts of result on separate lines? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest thing is just to pattern match.

```
main = do
    let (a,b,c) = autocorrelation $ V.fromList sampleA
    print a
    print b
    print c
```

Comment: Can I use mapM or mapM_ in some way?

Comment: @rnso in *this* case, yes, `case autocorrelation (V.fromList sampleA) of (a,b,c) -> mapM_ print [a,b,c]`, since `a,b,c` happen to be of the same type, `Vector Double`.

Comment: Thanks. Best to add this also in your answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you *really* don't want to pattern-match yourself, you can use [the fixed-vector package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fixed-vector-1.2.0.0) to help you. Note that it comes with its own `mapM_` that you'd have to use:

```
import Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Fixed as F
import Statistics.Autocorrelation
import Data.Typeable

sampleA = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4]

main = do
    let res = autocorrelation $ V.fromList sampleA
    putStr "Type of result of autocorrelation test: "
    print $ typeOf res
    print res
    F.mapM_ print res
```

Alternatively, you could make a `newtype` and stick your tuple in there:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}

import Data.Vector as V
import Statistics.Autocorrelation
import Data.Typeable

newtype Triple a = Triple (a, a, a) deriving(Foldable)

sampleA = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4]

main = do
    let res = autocorrelation $ V.fromList sampleA
    putStr "Type of result of autocorrelation test: "
    print $ typeOf res
    print res
    Prelude.mapM_ print $ Triple res
```

Answer (score 2):

We can make use of the [**`lens`** [Hackage]](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) package to transform a tuple into a list:

```
import Control.Lens(toListOf, each)
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import Statistics.Autocorrelation

sampleA = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4]

main :: IO ()
main = mapM_ print (toListOf each (autocorrelation (V.fromList sampleA)))
```

But it is probably better to do pattern matching like [@DanielWagner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57931884/67579) says, since then you make it more explicit what is happening.